# Why does Thunderbird keep telling me it's going to expire?

Tags: 10.04, thunderbird

Why does Thunderbird keep telling me it's going to expire? Shouldn't Ubuntu automatically update to the latest version?

My version of Thunderbird is Version 3.1.20. It's the default one that I selected when I installed Ubuntu.

Comment: What version is your thunderbird?

Comment: Version 3.1.20. It's the default one that I selected when I installed Ubuntu

Comment: ... what is the version of ubuntu you are using?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu will update Thunderbird, so just be patient.

See this bug report for more informations: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/972840

Note that you can already enable the *proposed* archive in Ubuntu, as it contain the latest release of Thunderbird.

Comment: This is the correct answer, there's no reason to install a PPA when an official update is on the way!

Answer (score 1):

Download the new version from http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/ and install it.Before that uninstall the old version.Ubuntu never do updation itself unless you installed it by PPA.

Comment: But will Ubuntu continue to update the new version? And why hasn't it been updating the current one each week?

Comment: I've looked up thunderbird in synaptic package manager, and the only version available is 3.1.20, the version I'm currently using, and thunderbird tells me it's going to expire today (24/04/12). I'm still confused as to why update manager isn't updating thunderbird. Does canonical not support thunderbird?

Comment: Update: I've run the following that I found on a similar question: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install thunderbird and now have the latest version of thunderbird (12.0). Unfortunately this still hasn't answered why package manager hasn't been regularly updating thunderbird along with every other package I have installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 11.10 and thunderbird automatically updates, when I first installed it it was on version 8 and is now version 11.
I don't have 10.04 installed so I can't check this but as it is quite old now they may not 
have been updating thunderbird in the repositories.